# How can I call an image from a user's input?

Tags: java, android

I have four images I'd like the user to choose from. I'd like the user to enter a number from 1 to 4, which will then result in the corresponding image being displayed. The non-selected images will be faded out (alpha 0) and the selected image faded in (alpha 1). I don't know how I can use a string containing the user's input to specify the image to animate.

Google / stack overflow searches haven't helped.

```
public void buttonClic (View view) {
  ImageView pic1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  ImageView pic2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
  ImageView pic3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
  ImageView pic4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
  Log.i("info", "OK, pictures have been assigned.");
  EditText number = findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);
  String str = number.getText().toString().trim();
  double val = 0;
  boolean enteredSmth = true;
  try {val = Integer.parseInt(str);}
  catch(NumberFormatException e) {enteredSmth = false;}
  if(enteredSmth) {
      enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
      Log.i("info", "OK, number entered has been parsed);
      if (enteredNumber<=4 && enteredNumber>=1){
          String desiredPic = "pic" + str;
          Log.i("info", "The user desires to view " + desiredPic + ".");
          pic1.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
          pic2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
          pic3.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
          pic4.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
          // Here is where I'd like the selected image, defined by 'desiredPic', to animate in.
      }
      else {Toast.makeText(this, "I'm no mathematician, but "+enteredNumber+" isn't from 1 to 4...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
  }
  else {Toast.makeText(this, "What, are you trying to crash the app?! Enter a NUMBER.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}
```

Comment: How about using array of ImageViews and iterate over the items , if i == user choice set alpha to 1 , else set alpha to 0

Comment: Ben, hadn't thought of arrays. It's working now - thanks!

Comment: sure no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 4 variables for each `ImageView`, use an array to store them and refer to them by index:

```
public void buttonClic (View view) {
    ImageView[] images = new ImageView[] {
            findViewById(R.id.imageView1),
            findViewById(R.id.imageView2),
            findViewById(R.id.imageView3),
            findViewById(R.id.imageView4)
    }
    Log.i("info", "OK, pictures have been assigned.");
    EditText number = findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);
    String str = number.getText().toString().trim();
    double val = 0;
    boolean enteredSmth = true;
    try {val = Integer.parseInt(str);}
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {enteredSmth = false;}
    if(enteredSmth) {
        enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        Log.i("info", "OK, number entered has been parsed");
        if (enteredNumber<=4 && enteredNumber>=1){
            String desiredPic = "pic" + str;
            Log.i("info", "The user desires to view " + desiredPic + ".");
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if (i != enteredNumber - 1)
                    images[i].animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
                else
                    images[i].animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "I'm no mathematician, but "+enteredNumber+" isn't from 1 to 4...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
    else {Toast.makeText(this, "What, are you trying to crash the app?! Enter a NUMBER.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}
```

Notice that the index of the pic chosen is **-1** the number chosen by the user.